# Wrong color figures in pdf output

Tags: graphics, xetex, color, pdf

I am composing a large number of pdf figures with `includegraphics` that contain pixel graphics with xelatex. The individual figures are themselves compiled with xelatex using `includegraphics`. As the original pixel graphics, the pdf figures have a colored a (light yellow) background.

In the composed document in some (but not all) of the figures the background appears in greenish color that I do not use anywhere else in the document.

How come that xelatex (pdflatex seems to do the same) replaces the background color of these figures and how can I fix or even debug that?

The document is big and I did not manage to reproduce the effect in a smaller file so far. I am using texlive on ubuntu.
and experience this problem in with different pdf viewers and also in prints.

Comment: Does this happen with other PDF viewers as well? Also, if you could specify, for example, are these figures created with Latex and if so, how? TikZ? Or other methods?

Comment: I will try to answer the first question later. I had seen the problem with different pdf viewers on the screen but do not know if it appears also when printing from these. The figures are created also with xelatex/pdflatex. After creation I decompose the multi-page files with `pdftk` and crop them by adjusting their BoundingBox/MediaBox. The problem seems to occur with some but not all of the figures I prepare in this way and is not visible in the separate figures before I compile them.

Comment: @highsciguy: Try to avoid using `pdftk` and instead include the pdfs directly and clip them. Do the colour problems persist?